# Spring: How to get parameters from POST body?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Web-service using spring in which I have to get the params from the body of my post request? The content of the body is like:-

```
source=”mysource”

&json=
{
    "items": [
        {
            "username": "test1",
            "allowed": true
        },
        {
            "username": "test2",
            "allowed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And the web-service method looks like:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", headers="Content-Type=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(@RequestBody String a) throws MyException {
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(uiRequestProcessor.saveData(a),HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Please let me know how do I get the params from the body? I can get the whole body in my string but I don't think that would be a valid approach. Please let me know how do I proceed further.

Comment: If you're trying to consume a JSON object your request is not valid.

Comment: @Bart So i should use headers="Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ?? right

Comment: No, you will need to send the JSON object in the request body with contentType *application/json*. Your handler should accept a object representing your JSON object as an argument.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get param from request.

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Model model){
   String jsonString = request.getParameter("json");
}
```

Comment: what should be the headers for the request, getting null in request.getParameter("json");

Comment: Thanks it worked after changing content type to :-headers="Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: I'm pretty new to Java and Spring. What does the "Model model" do ? I'm confused.

Answer (score 27):

You can get entire post body into a POJO. Following is something similar

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = { "/api/pojo/edit" }, 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    produces = "application/json", 
    consumes = ["application/json"])
@ResponseBody
public Boolean editWinner( @RequestBody Pojo pojo) {
```

Where each field in Pojo (Including getter/setters) should match the Json request object that the controller receives..

Answer (score 7):

You can bind the json to a POJO using `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` . Thus your controller signature can read :-

```
  public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(@RequestBody RequestDTO req)
```

Where RequestDTO needs to be a bean appropriately annotated to work with jackson serializing/deserializing. Your *-servlet.xml file should have the Jackson message converter registered in RequestMappingHandler as follows :-

```
  <list >
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

  </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This won't solve described problem MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter expects standard json, so it will throw MappingException while processing body, since the format is not plain json

Comment: It's close though, and doesn't use the raw request and response (WTF?) like in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using @RequestBodyParam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", headers="Content-Type=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(@RequestBodyParam String source,@RequestBodyParam JsonDto json) throws MyException {
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/LambdaExpression/RequestBodyParam

Answer (score 2):

In class do like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(
    HttpServletResponse response,
    Bean beanName
) throws MyException {
    return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(uiRequestProcessor.saveData(a), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In page do like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/saveData" method="post" name="saveForm" id="saveForm">
<input type="text" value="${beanName.userName }" id="username" name="userName" />

</from>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need these imports...

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

And, if you're using Maven, you'll also need this in the dependencies block of the pom.xml file in your project's base directory.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then the above-listed fix by Jason will work:

```
@ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> saveData(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model){
        String jsonString = request.getParameter("json");
    }
```