# Create restController method post for service method with two objects

Tags: java, rest

I have a method in service where i add person to team :

```
@Transactional
    public void addPersonsToTeams(Long teamId, Long personId) {
        Assert.notNull(personId, "Object can't be null!");
        Assert.notNull(teamId, "Object can't be null!");
        try {
            Person person = personRepository.getOne(personId);
            Team team = teamRepository.getOne(teamId);
            person.getTeams().add(team);
            personRepository.save(person);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CreateEntityException();
        }

    }
```

Now in my rest controller class i want to create a post method to test it in postman. But this my first time with two arguments method and i don't know how to create it. 
Actually i have only this:

```
@PostMapping("/addPeopleToTeams")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addPeopleToTeam(@RequestBody Long teamId, Long personId){

    }
```

This is good way? Maybe somebody have some exaple?

Answer (score 0):

You can get entire post body into a POJO. Following is something similar

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/api/pojo/edit" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Boolean addPeopleToTeam( @RequestBody Pojo pojo) { return false; }
```

Where each field in Pojo (Including getter/setters) should match the Json request object that the controller receives.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163397/spring-how-to-get-parameters-from-post-body?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: But I use dto and modelmapper

Comment: Just replace the pojo with your dto, pass the json as a body in the post request.

Comment: But in your example i don't see my method addPeopleToTeam. I need use this method and this method have two arguments both classes id

Comment: You can update your method to use a Pojo as an argument, then when you pass a json, with param same name as those defined inside your pojo, it will be filled. Then you can use the setter method to get the info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put `teamId` as a `@PathVariable`. This way, you will call `/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}` with `personId` in `@RequestBody`. Or, you could also sent a json formed like this :

```
{ 
   "personId" : "xx",
   "teamId" : "xx"
}
```

Then, you can call it the way you do it with a `/addPeopleToTeams` with this object in `@RequestBody`. You can pretty much do it a lot of differents ways. Just do it the way it make the most sense in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/addPeopleToTeams/{teamId}/{personId}" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Boolean addPeopleToTeam( @PathVariable("teamId") Long teamId, @PathVariable("personId")  Long personId)
```

But you need to invoke your method like that `/addPeopleToTeams/1/2`