# Send image with difference data type from angular 7 to Rest API in spring boot 2.0.5

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multipartform-data

I searched a lot in "stack overflow" and in other sites, no answer resolve my problem.

**Angular html file:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit">
  <div>
    <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="data.image" name="image" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
  </div>

  <div class="form">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.clientName" name="clientName">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  //........ Other inputs fields here//
</form>
```

**Angular ts file:**

```
public confirmAdd(): void {
  const payload: FormData = new FormData();
  payload.append('clientName', this.data.clientName);
  payload.append('dateOfBirth', this.data.dateOfBirth.toString());
  payload.append('mobileNumber', this.data.mobileNumber);
  payload.append('email', this.data.email);
  //...............other fields here ..........//
  payload.append('image', this.selectedFile); == > the image
}
```

**Angular Service ts file:**

```
private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content- Type': 'multipart/form-data'
});

this.http.post(this.urlEndTestImage, payload {
  headers: this.httpHeaders
}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
});
```

**spring boot Rest API:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {
  "http://localhost:4200"
})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apiHorsesClub")

public class ClienteRestController {

  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public String uploadMultipartFile(@RequestParam("model") String clientNew, @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image) {
    try {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      clientEntity client = mapper.readValue(clientNew, clientEntity.class);
      client.setImage(image.getBytes());
      clientService.save(client);
      return "successfully -> filename=" + image.getOriginalFilename();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "FAIL!file's size > 500KB";
    }
  }
}
```

I am try to add more `@RequestParam()` and I am try `@RequestPart(`)  with the same name of fields but not work.

This image of postman request post:

[image: it's work no problem and save the image with data to mySql]

Comment: Cannot see any issue in your code. Actually what is your problem?

Comment: Angular cannot send the data by post method

Comment: Oh i did not see it. see my answer

Comment: Try this `payload.append('model', this.data);` instead of passing seperate attribute. So remove `clientName`, `dateOfBirth`, `mobileNumber` and `email`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, the problem as you say @Sudarshana i don't match "model" in angular side, and after a lot search i found two method to send file with difference data:

1. Send by (Data JSON, file)

   **Angular html:**

   ```
   <form   [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
       <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" formControlName="clientName" placeholder="client Name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input type="text" formControlName="age"  placeholder="Age">
      <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
   </form>
   ```

   **Angular ts:**

   ```
   profileForm = new FormGroup({
   clientName : new FormControl(''),
   lastName : new FormControl(''),
   age : new FormControl('')
   });

   selectedFile = null;
   public data:clientClass = new clientClass();

   onFileSelected(event) {
   this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
   console.log(this.selectedFile);
   }

   onSubmit() {
   let object = this.profileForm.value;
   const payload = new FormData();
   payload.append("addClient",JSON.stringify(object));
   payload.append("image", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
   this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/yourAPI/uploadTestEntity`,payload, { 
   responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
     (object) => {
       this.profileForm.reset();
     });
   }
   ```

   **App modules file:**

   ```
   import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   @NgModule({
   imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule ]
   })
   ```

   **Rest API:**

   ```
   @PostMapping("/uploadTestEntity")
   public String uploadTestEntity(
   @RequestParam("addClient") String clientNameEntityNew,    
   @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image) {
     try {
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         testEntity testEntity = mapper.readValue(clientNameEntityNew,testEntity.class);
         testEntity.setImage(image.getBytes());
         TestEntityService.save(testEntity);
       return "File uploaded successfully! -> filename = "+ image.getOriginalFilename();
         } catch (  Exception e) {
     return "FAIL! Maybe You had uploaded the file before or the file's size > 500KB";
   }    
   }
   ```

   2- send file and Data as params and receive as params in Rest API:

   **Angular html:**

   ```
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
    </div>
   <div>
   <input id="textauthor" [(ngModel)]="clientName" name="clientName" placeholder="Name">
   <input id="textauthor" [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="last 
   Name">
   <input id="textauthor" [(ngModel)]="age" name="age" placeholder="age">
   <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
   </div>
   </form>
   ```

   **Angular ts:**

   ```
   clientName:string;
   lastName:string;
   age:string;
   resData: any;
   selectedFile = null;

   onFileSelected(event) {
   this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
   console.log(this.selectedFile);

   onSubmit() {
   const payload = new FormData();
   payload.append('clientName', this.clientName);
   payload.append('lastName', this.lastName);
   payload.append('age', this.age);
   payload.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

   this.http.post(`http://localhost:8080/apiHorsesClub/uploadTestEntity`,
   payload).subscribe((data: any) => { this.resData = data;console.log(this.resData);
     });
   }
   ```

   **Rest API:**

   ```
   @PostMapping("/uploadTestEntity")
   public String uploadTestEntity(
            @RequestParam("clientName") String clientName ,
            @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName
            @RequestParam("age") String age
           ,@RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image) {
     try {

         testEntity testEntity = new testEntity();
         testEntity.setImage(image.getBytes());
         testEntity.setClientName(clientName);
         testEntity.setLastName(lastName);
         testEntity.setAge(age);
       return "File uploaded successfully! -> filename = "+ image.getOriginalFilename();
   } catch (  Exception e) {
     return "FAIL! Maybe You had uploaded the file before or the file's size > 500KB";
   }    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You have missed **`,`** in your **`Service`**.

```
   private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content- Type':'multipart/form-data'});
       this.http.post(this.urlEndTestImage, payload, { headers:this.httpHeaders })
       .subscribe(
           res => {  console.log(res) } );
```

Comment: not work, i will send image of the errors in eclipse, the problem how send name of the fields

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with Sprint-boot. But you are sending data as `FormData` it means inside `HTTP POST` body. you cannot catch it using `RequestParam`. And your Backend API is needed a parameter as model but you are not sending it from angular side. See below. you will get some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163397/spring-how-to-get-parameters-from-post-body

Comment: the problem with upload the file with the data

Comment: Check using postman whether your backend is working as you needed

Comment: You are sending **model** field in your `FormData` no ? bcoz error in you added image is related with model attribute