# Spring JPA: find by multiple IDs with Pagination

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, pagination

How is it possible to apply the pagination to the below query:

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

  @Query("select b from Building b where b.id in :ids" )
  Page<Post> findByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> postIdsList);
...
}
```

All the existing examples are based on the standard `findAll` method that accepts a `Pageable` object: `public Page findAll(Pageable pageable);`.

The questions are:

- what the controller method signature should be
- what the repository method parameters should be
- how and what parameters should be passed into the controller method
- should I always split the post IDs for every request
- will Spring make a single query and keep all the found posts in memory or it will hit a query every time for every next/previous page? If so, how can it figure out the IDs to use to find the next/previous posts?

The initial implementation was as follows:

```
@RestController
class PostsController {

    @Autowired

    private PostService postService;

    @GetMapping("/posts", params = "ids")
    public List<Post> getPaginatedPosts(@RequestParam List<Long> ids) {

        return postService.findPaginatedPosts(ids);
    }
}

@Repository
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

  @Query("select b from Building b where b.id in :ids" )
  Page<Post> findByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> postIdsList);
...
}
```

I omitted the code from the `PostServiceImpl` qui implements the `PostService` and just calls the `PostRepository#findByIds` method.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-pagination-in-spring

Comment: This begs the question: if the client knows the ids it should fetch, why isn't paging handled there by simply limiting the list of ids sent in the request?

Comment: @crizzis: because there are more than 20 IDs on the front side and it is easier to just tweak the URL by adding paging/sorting parameters than playing with the collection and cutting it here and there for every page. So I prefer to let Spring do it in place. More of that, I think this is how most pagination libraries work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I came to you coupled with the above comments suggestions.

1. Define a repository either extending `JpaRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`as follows:

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

  @Query("select p from Post p where p.id in :ids" )
  Page<Post> findByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> postIdsList);
...
}
```

2. Create a service class and its implementation:

```java
public interface PostService {
  List<PostDTO> getPostsList(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
...
}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {
...
  @Autowired
  private PostRepository postRepository;

...
  @Override
  public List<PostDTO> getPostsList(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable) {
        List<PostDTO> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        Page<Post> paginatedPosts = postRepository.findByIds(ids, pageable);

        List<Post> posts = paginatedPosts.getContent();
        posts.forEach(post -> resultList.add(convertToPostDTO(post)));

        return resultList;
    }
```

And finally, the `PostsController` part:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class PostsController {

  @Autowired
  private PostService postService;
...
    @GetMapping(value = "/posts", params = "ids")
    public ResponseEntity <List<PostDTO>>getPostsList(@RequestParam List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable) {
        List<PostDTO> postsList = postService.getPostsList(ids, pageable);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(postsList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The request should contain `page` and `size` URL parameters (by default, `page` is `0` and `size` is `20`):

```
http://localhost:8080/api/posts?ids=1050,1049,1048,1043,1042,1041,1040,1039,1038&size=5&page=1&sort=id
```

In the above example, I had 9 records total and I put the parameters explicitly to limit the result list to 5 and display the second page only as well as to sort them by id.

If you don't provide them, the default values will be used (page = 0, size = 20).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```java
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long> {

  @Query( "select o from Building b where id in :ids" )
  Page<Post> findByIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> postIdsList,Pageable pageRequest);
...
}
```

In controller ask for pageSize and pageNo, if it is empty set a default value like pageNo = 0, pageSize=10.

pass these values to to service layer service should create pageable object call `findByIds(ids, pagable);` and return the page to controller.

you can refer this:
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/

Comment: Thank you for the link, even if it is dated of 2012, it is still useful :). I also took a look at the latest [Spring Data Rest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting) docs.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming here looking to pass a list of ids as a url-parameter like the question asker wants to do and the answer of belgoros explains:

**Be aware of the url-max-length of 2048 characters.**

So if your list of ids is long enough to require pagination, you probably also want to make the ids a body-parameter. This answer explains how to create body-parameters with spring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22163492/7465516

I think this is important, because solutions that work on small data but unexpectedly fail on big data are the kind of thing that gets through testing and fails in production.

(I do not have the reputation to make this a comment, I hope this post is acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

@Query( "select o from Building b where id in :ids", nativeQuery=true )
Page findByIds(@Param("ids") List postIdsList,Pageable pageRequest);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).